# split a large csv file according to some NaN values

Tags: pandas, csv

There is a huge file, almost reaching 10 million rows, which I would like to split based on the values of a given column. One represents internal measurements (inside a house) and the other one is the external data (outside). This codes takes way too long to split, any ideas?

```
fext = open('external.csv', 'a')
fint = open('internal.csv', 'a')

for df in pd.read_csv('todo.csv', parse_dates=['Measured At'], 
                  low_memory=False, chunksize=500000):
    dfExt = df[df['Temperatura Exterior'].notnull()]
    dfInt = df[df['Temperatura Exterior'].isnull()]
    dfExt.to_csv(fext,header=False)
    dfInt.to_csv(fint,header=False)

fext.close();fint.close()
```

Comment: From your description it sounds like you don't need a for loop at all. A simple df = pd.read_csv(...) should be enough.

Comment: I can't load a 10M row file into memory. Besides, it needs to be split into two files depending on whether one variable is NaN or not.

Comment: I see. Have you been able to load anything so far? How long is each pass taking? Are you sure you need to use parse_dates if you are immediately saving off the data anyways? You may be able to get some speedup without parse_dates.

Comment: Thanks Leo, you are right. I don't need the date column to be a date until much later in the analysis. I skipped it and the code runs 25x faster!! I can now read the whole file in about a minute, as opposed to about half an hour.